# JSON RPC sendTransaction data paramether

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, json-rpc

I'm trying to make a sendTransaction json rpc call and I don't know how to calculate the data paramether.

From the documentation:

```
data: DATA - The compiled code of a contract OR the hash of the invoked method signature and encoded parameters. For details see Ethereum Contract ABI
```

There is no specification how this should be made: **the hash of the invoked method signature and encoded parameters**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's an [Application Binary Interface Specification](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html)

> The Application Binary Interface is the standard way to interact with contracts in the Ethereum ecosystem, both from outside the blockchain and for contract-to-contract interaction. Data is encoded according to its type, as described in this specification. The encoding is not self describing and thus requires a schema in order to decode.

There are several questions here about it:

- [How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api)
- [Getting "data" for JSON RPC eth_call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17444/getting-data-for-json-rpc-eth-call)

Comment: Yeah but I'm not trying to communicate with a contract just a simple eth transfer..

Comment: That is really easy, data should be empty.

Comment: So its an none optional paramether but it has to be empty?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself correctly, I meant it can be empty. Usualy an empty data is enough, but you can embed any string there. Some application use data to embed a transaction id for example.

Comment: Sorry, coming in late. Could you invoke another method from a smart contract (using the data field) thus deceiving the transfer the user thought it was signing? I am afraid after signing such a message. Or is it purely informative in the case of this kind of transaction? Thanks

Comment: @Nre It will be better if you create a new question for that. You can link to this one if it helps to set the context.